# JavaScript function -- Next Page

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create a function that will go from one question page to the next via a button. So there is a button that links to the next question and in the url it should go to 2 from 1 and so on.

I created a function but it only goes to /1 or /11. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<button onclick="incPage();">Next Question</button>
<script>
  var i = 1;
  var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/SAT/" + i;

  function incPage() {
    if (i < 1000) {
      i++;
      window.location = url;
    } else if (i = 10) {
      i = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = i;
  }

  function decPage() {
    if (i > 0) {
      --i;
      window.location = url;
    } else if (i = 0) {
      i = 10;
    }
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = i;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems with your code:

1. You didn't update URL after you call the function.
2. else if in the first function is useless because if-block will be true. Change the order.

```
<button onclick="changePage(1);">Next Question</button>
<button onclick="changePage(-1);">Prev Question</button>

var currentPage = 1;
var maxPage = 1000;
const changePage = (num) => {
  let pageNum = currentPage + num
  currentPage = pageNum < 1 ? 1 : pageNum > maxPage ? maxPage : pageNum;
  window.location = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/SAT/${currentPage}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`url` will always be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/SAT/1` because you've assigned the `+ i` before doing anything with the function.

If you just assign your main url at the start then you can append the index (i) inside the incPage function.